# application.properties value is not being evaluated correctly across platforms

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my spring boot batch (2.7.3) `application.properties` file I have:

```
rs.input.path=/opt/ingestiondata/rs
```

Afterthat, when I do a `mvn clean install` on my windows machine, I get the jar file in my `target`  folder. When I try to do `java -jar myjar.jar` on my local windows command prompt, it give **(as expected, as there is no such path)** exception - `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \opt\ingestiondata\rs`

Then I move the same jar file to the linux box there when I do java -jar myjar.jar my key `rs.input.path` get evaluated to a windows path - `c:\users\ajay\some\dir`.

What can be wrong here? As I am using the same jar. Its odd but its what happening since last couple of hours. Tried and verified `killall java` etc etc and now running out of options. Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated. Must be something trivial and something horrible I am expecting.

**Update:**
As asked by Abhijit, this is how this is being used.

```
    @Value("${rs.input.path}")
    private String inputPath;   
    
    @Bean
    ItemReader<File> myReader() throws IOException {
        List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(inputPath))
                            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                            .map(Path::toFile)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new IteratorItemReader<>(files);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code where this path is used. Also elaborate how do you determine what the path is being resolved to.

Comment: Added more info Abhijit. Please let me know if more details are requried. And this is all I have related to `rs.input.path` in my entire project. I deleted the project. Recreated and retried multiple times, same result.

Comment: I don’t believe the problem is what you’re describing. There is no way for the jar to be aware of your Windows home directory unless you tell it to. There is another source from where this property is overridden with a higher priority. Depending on your Spring foo, you can try to debug the code for the value resolver. An alternative method of debugging is to use `ConfigurationProperties` that tracks the source. And, try printing that value upon entering the bean method.

Comment: Also run the jar with `—debug` and read the wealth of information there.

Comment: If you’re still struggling, post a minimum reproducible example to reproduce the issue. Otherwise it’s anyone’s guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in a spring application,
for any property,
there can't be multiple values;
unless you are using multiple profile specific 'application.properties' files which are specific to each environment.

Option 1:

"""

Check where your property is residing:
'rs.annual.path=/your/linux/path'

Suppose, let's assume it's inside
application-dev.properties

So, you need to select "dev" as Spring profile.

Try running the jar again, by pass passing profile.

(Spring_Property)

1. java -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

(Vm_Argument)

2.java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev myjar.jar

"""

Option 2:

"""

Since you are running your jar file inside linux.

Try passing path directly as argument.

(Spring_Property)

1. java -jar myjar.jar --rs.annual.path=/your/linux/path

You can pass the property as argument. So the Argument-property will taken precedence over Application-property.

"""

Comment: Thanks Sanjay. But there is no profile. Just default application.properties only. --rs.annual.path=/your/linux/path comes into picture if are using profiles or intentionally want to override. I understand what you are saying but this a weird situation.

Comment: Since the OP didn’t say they are using profiles, I don’t think that your instructions for activating profiles is very relevant to the question. Also, the question isn’t how to set the property from the command line but why is it not picking up the expected value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).